# How can I create a PDF file programmatically in an iOS application?

Tags: ios, pdf

How to generate a PDF file on a user action?

Comment: Are you looking for a code sample on how to create a PDF?

Comment: yes, that will be appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See ["Drawing with Quartz"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) to see how to create a PDF Graphics Context.

Some notes:

> "iPhoneOSNote: If you want to create a PDF graphics context in an iPhone application, make sure you also read “Drawing to a Graphics Context in iPhone OS” (page 27)."

> "You can write any content to a PDF that’s appropriate for your application—images, text, path drawing—and you can add links and encryption. For more information see “PDF Document Creation, Viewing, and Transforming” (page 177)."

Answer (score 2):

As an example of creating a PDF from the contents of a CALayer, you can refer to the -dataForPDFRepresentationOfLayer method within the [CPLayer class](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/source/browse/framework/Source/CPLayer.m) in the [Core Plot framework](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/).  You can do something similar to extract the content from a CALayer-backed UIView, although we had to subclass CALayer in order to get vector elements to render to a PDF properly.

Answer (score 0):

Use this library to generate pdf file by programmatically.

[SJ_PDFCreator](https://github.com/sumitjagdev/SJ_PDFCreator)

Answer (score -1):

Use a web service on a server back end to post the data to - then generate the PDF and return it to the browser/app with the correct mime type to open as a PDF.

ColdFusion could easily do this for you in just a few lines of code.

Comment: Not much use if you don't have an active connection.