# Create pdf inapp iOS

Tags: ios, pdf, pdf-generation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create a PDF file programmatically in an iOS application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360912/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-file-programmatically-in-an-ios-application)

I'm looking to create a pdf document in my iPad app, and email it after creation.
The document will always have different size (also many pages size), because it should contain a set of table rows, every time in a different number.