# How to convert .png image to .pdf in iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, pdf

How to convert image of format .png to .pdf file?

Comment: please refer this-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360912/how-can-i-create-a-pdf-file-programmatically-in-an-iphone-application you will findout!

Comment: have you a single image of .png file or you have set of images to convert image to pdf ?

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to create PDF file from image.

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(20, 100, 300, 60);
NSString* fileName = @"FileName.PDF";

NSArray *arrayPaths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* pdfFileName = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
// Create the PDF context using the default page size of 612 x 792.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
// Mark the beginning of a new page.
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

[image drawInRect:frame];

// Close the PDF context and write the contents out.
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

Answer (score -3):

```
-(void)createPdf:(NSImage*)image
{  
    PDFDocument *pdf = [[PDFDocument alloc] init];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
    PDFPage *page = [[PDFPage alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [pdf insertPage:page atIndex: [pdf pageCount]];
    [pdf writeToFile:path];
}
```

**USE the above method as follow :**

```
 NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:PATH_OF_YOUR_PNG_FILE];
    [self createPdf:image];
```

Comment: What is PDFDocument and PDFPage here? OP has asked about iPhone development.